# Input Unicode characters in Pluto.jl

Tags: julia, pluto.jl

Just wondering if anyone knows how to add Unicode input in `pluto.jl`. For example, if I want to input a Unicode character for sigma, I would type `\sigma` in vs code, and the autocomplete will change it to `σ`. Any ideas how I could do the same in `pluto.jl`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do the same in pluto: type `\sigma`, then hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> and it should change to `σ`.

Comment: Alternatively (e.g. for characters which do not have a Latex style tab completion), you can copy / paste unicode characters from any website (e.g. https://unicode-table.com/) to Pluto.